# What does WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate() do

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a class to handle impersonation and delegation for use in in asp.net, WCF services, and WinForms apps.

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() returns a WindowsIdentity object that represents the current Windows user.

And

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), WindowsIdentity.Impersonate allows code to impersonate a different Windows user.

So, what effect does impersonating the current user have, and more importantly, in a web app, how can WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() return other than the process starter identity or the already impersonated end user?

Comment: It's a long story and has many restrictions, but suppose you want to do an action in your web-app on behalf of your user(with his credentials) such as reading eMails & displaying in a page, this is where impersonation comes in.

Comment: @Russell McClure  I have both web apps and winforms apps.  The issue is to use Kerberos to pass the user to a SQL server using their own rights, but to do logging with the process starter identity.

Comment: Windows security is very strongly tied to the rights of a user account.  Trying to assign rights to an existing account is difficult and error prone.  Impersonate another user, get the rights you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Impersonate()` throws a `SecurityException` if a Win32 error occurs. Therefore, chances are it's implemented through a Win32 function, most probably [ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612.aspx).

Its documentation says (emphasis mine):

> All impersonate functions, including `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` allow the
>   requested impersonation if one of the following is true:
>
> - The requested impersonation level of the token is less than `SecurityImpersonation`, such as `SecurityIdentification` or
>     `SecurityAnonymous`.
> - The caller has the `SeImpersonatePrivilege` privilege.
> - A process (or another process in the caller's logon session) created the token using explicit credentials through `LogonUser` or
>     `LsaLogonUser` function.
> - **The authenticated identity is same as the caller.**

Therefore, I'm strongly inclined to think that `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate()` will successfully establish a new impersonation layer to the same user.

Concerning the second part of your question, you seem to be confusing `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` with [HttpContext.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx). In a web application, `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` always returns the thread owner (usually `Network Service`), and `HttpContext.User` returns the currently authenticated user, if any.

Comment: So, it sounds like it does nothing.

Comment: Nope, far from that. It *actually creates* the new impersonation layer. `Impersonate()` returns a [WindowsImpersonationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx) that you have to [Undo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.undo%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) afterwards in order to pop that layer off the stack and avoid leaking an impersonation context.

Comment: My question stems from seeing WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate() in several pages I google'd.  I get the difference between the thread owner and the HttpContext user.  I was worried that there could be a case where WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() would return something other than the current thread owner identity.  If it is always the same, it sounds like Impersonate() does impersonate, but is there any effect or reason to do this on the current WindowsIdentity?

Comment: The effect would be to have the thread handling the web request impersonate some other user, so it can indeed be useful, but I'm confused: are you saying you found code like `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate()` somewhere on the web? If so, can you update your question with the relevant parts of that code?

Comment: I did.  It looked stupid to me, but it is out there in more than one place.  Either the authors of that code are ignorant, or I am.  My assumption was that it was me.

Comment: Still no one has answered what the benefit is of impersonating the _current user_ again, which was the initial question. Yes, it creates a new impersonation context of the same user. But why is this done?

Answer (score 0):

The current user is important if you have to run a user through multiple applications, including some that would normally allow anonymous access, as well. In addition, it allows you to explicitly do what is done implicitly in certain types of applications.

From your standpoint, the more important thing may be to understand that not all application types automatically get the startup user type in the manner you would like. In these cases, there are some instances where you can programmatically accomplish getting identity and then using it for your own means (nefarious or otherwise?).

As far as impersonating another user, that gets to be interesting when you get outside of some of the declarative situations (like ASP.NET impersonation). This is for good reason, so a hacker does not create an application with God like rights, for example.